# Не срабатывает read

Tags: pascal

Я использую переменную: `a: string`. Для того чтобы не закрывалась **CMD**  и пользователь успел разглядеть результат: `read (a)`.

Почему это помогает в других проектах, а именно в этом  не помогает?

```
var god, rost: integer; a: string;

begin 
    Write('Ваш рост (в см): '); // Получаем данные в переменную rost 
    Read(rost);

    Write('Ваш возраст : '); // Получаем данные в переменную god
    Read(god);
    Writeln('');

    begin

        if (rost > 130 ) then
            Writeln('Ваш рост - ', rost)
        else 
            Writeln('Ошибка ввода: Минимальный вводимый рост 130 см.');

        if (god >= 12 ) then
            Writeln('Вам ', god, ' лет' )
        else
            Writeln('Ошибка ввода: Минимальный вводимый возраст 12 лет');
    end;

    Writeln('Ваш идеальный вес: ', rost - 110 );

    read (a)
end.
```

---

```
var
  god, rost: integer;
  a: string;


begin
  Write('Ваш рост (в см): ');                                        // Получаем данные в переменную   rost
  Read(rost);


  Write('Ваш возраст : ');                                           // Получаем данные в переменную   god  
  Read(god);

  Writeln('');





 begin


    if (rost > 130 ) then

      Writeln('Ваш рост - ', rost)






    else 

      Writeln('Ошибка ввода: Минимальный вводимый рост 130 см.');



    if (god >= 12 ) then

      Writeln('Вам ', god, ' лет' )



    else

      Writeln('Ошибка ввода: Минимальный вводимый возраст 12 лет');


   end;



  Writeln('Ваш идеальный вес: ', rost - 110 );

  read (a)


end.
```

Comment: @Igor Вопрос отредактируйте, чтобы показать код

Comment: _а именно в этом не помогает?_ - а что происходит? В показанном коде похоже лишний begin

Comment: У Вас после чтения `integer` в буфере ввода остаётся перевод строки. `read(a)` его успешно читает без необходимости какого-либо дополнительного ввода от пользователя.

Comment: Убирал begin, end;.  Не помогало   что-то я не понимаю.

Comment: А если заменить все `read` на `readln`? И кстати, их можно запускать без параметров, соответственно переменная `a` вам не нужна.

Comment: Пробовал запускать без переменной, не работало. (Консоль исчезала)     если  readln то тоже не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не рекомендовал считывать данные через `read`, с ним постоянно переносы строк теряются. Его стоит заменить на `readln`. Плюс, переменная `a` вам вообще не нужна.

```
var
  god, rost: integer;

begin
  Write('Ваш рост (в см): '); // Получаем данные в переменную rost
  Readln(rost);

  Write('Ваш возраст : '); // Получаем данные в переменную god
  Readln(god);

  begin
    if rost > 130 then
      Writeln('Ваш рост - ', rost)
    else
      Writeln('Ошибка ввода: Минимальный вводимый рост 130 см.');

    if god >= 12 then
      Writeln('Вам ', god, ' лет')
    else
      Writeln('Ошибка ввода: Минимальный вводимый возраст 12 лет');
  end;

  Writeln('Ваш идеальный вес: ', rost - 110);    
  Readln;
end.
```